# Error while decoding an optional parameter on Swift

Tags: swift, parameters, decode, option-type

Trying to decode a server response. It contains an optional parameters, like below

```
struct name {
    let id: String
    let name: String?
}

extension OrganizationV1: Decodable {
    enum orgCodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id
        case name
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let map = try decoder.container(keyedBy: orgCodingKeys.self)

        id = try map.decode(String.self, forKey: .id)
        name = try map.decode(String.self, forKey: .name)
    }
}
```

Getting an error on parsing data:

```
keyNotFound(orgCodingKeys(stringValue: "name", intValue: nil), Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [_JSONKey(stringValue: "Index 0", intValue: 0)], debugDescription: "No value associated with key orgCodingKeys(stringValue: \"name\", intValue: nil) (\"name\").", underlyingError: nil))
Could not be decoded network response.
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that Api response does not have `name` field or its type not matching with response or there is some spelling mistake. so it is giving this error. See the response from api if `name` is coming or not.

Comment: That property is optional, some objects has it, some of them doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was on try keyword.

The correct decoding of optional parameter should contain question mark, as I showed below.

```
name = try? map.decode(String?.self, forKey: .name)
```

Comment: No, not exactly. You don't need a custom decoder. You can delete your extension and conform your struct to decodable protocol to make it work as well.

Comment: `struct name: Decodable { let id: String; let name: String? }` This is all you need. Note that I added `;` just to make it a one liner for this comment.